# Data Warehouse: Who initiate extract data from multiple source to staging area, is it the source or the data warehouse?

Tags: database, microservices, etl, data-warehouse

I have a question regarding ETL (especially the extract one) in the data warehouse.

From this [article](https://data-warehouses.net/architecture/staging.html), a staging area is mainly for timing reasons and some don't even need a staging area.

Let say I have 3 microservice servers, each one has its own database, 2 operational servers, and 1 data warehouse server.

1. Server 1: data is scheduled to be extracted daily
2. Server 2: data is needed to be real-time available at the data warehouse

Who will initiate extract data? my thought is

1. Server 1: data extracting is initiated by the data warehouse server, extract directly from Server 1's database, scheduled daily
2. Server 2: the timing is cannot be scheduled, so the data warehouse server provides API for use by Server 2, and Server 2 initiates data extraction or rather sent data to the data warehouse server through provided API every time data is available.

But I'm not sure about it, should I provides API to all operational servers and let them decide when to send data to the warehouse? Or is it all the data warehouse server job to extract data directly from the operational database? If so, how to extract the real-time one?

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed approach (you ping server 1 daily but receive data from server 2 in near real time) is what I've seen in the past. A few things you might want to consider, though, are:

- Sometimes Server 2 can't be configured to automatically ping an API, frequently because its database won't support triggers. If this is the case, then you might need to ping server 2 periodically from the DW, like every five minutes.
- Typically, you would query server 1 every night. That said, I could see how it might actually be better for server 1 to just tell you when it's ready to be read. In that second case your DW doesn't have to worry about synchronizing with server 1's schedule; if server 1 has processing delays or its batch window runs long, your DW will still pick up its data when that data is ready.